# Newton's method with recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I was given a question where I should yet again use recursion to solve with. It's about newton's method. The algorithm works pretty fine with small numbers but suddenly when I give out larger numbers, the program goes into a loop.

This is what I was given as a description to  Newton's Method:

First I was asked to start off with a =x

1. If  |a*a-x|<= epsilon, then a is the square root of x within the tolerance; otherwise
2. Replace a with (a*a+x)/(2*a) and repeat Step 1

this is my code: x is the number to that I should get the square root off, and e is the tolerance

```
public static double sqrtR (int x, double e, int a) {

    if (Math.abs(a * a - x) <= e) {
        return a;
    } else {
        a = (a * a + x) / (2 * a);
        return 1.0 *(sqrtR(x, e, a));
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried changing int to long ?

Comment: no I haven't..but which int are you referring to?

Comment: instead of int x, int a, use long x, long a

Comment: @RamonBoza is right, you are probably getting integer overflows.

Comment: If I were you i'd step through your code in your debugger and check to make sure that you're actually approaching your base case.

Comment: I did debug, and yes i was approaching the basecase

Comment: Actually why aren't x,a doubles? The a = (a * a + x) / (2 * a) is going to cause problems with truncation

Comment: x is not a double mainly because I should actually get the square root of x

Comment: and I should get the square root of a non negative integer

Comment: there's actually a astack overflow whenever i send e as 0

Comment: Of course you get a stack overflow when `e` is zero, and you can safely change all arguments to `double` because you're already returning a `double`.

Comment: but if the e was 0 this means i want the square root to actually be like really precise

Comment: Dumb question: If `a` and `x` are integers, what's the point of checking a computation involving those integers against an "epsilon"?

Comment: im not quite sure myself..that's basically the problem of me not what's wrong actually

Comment: At a minimum you want `a` to be a double, because the square root of an integer is not usually an integer. Limiting your square root guesses to integers is unlikely to converge to a solution, giving stack overflow on the recursion.

Comment: thanks for that! that helps, I didn't take that into consideration at the start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in using an int - the program oscillates back and forth between two values if your epsilon is too small.

For example, with the function as you have it now `sqrtR(99999999,0.1,99999999)` ends up cycling between 9999 and 10000. Converting `int a` to `double a` would allow this to stop the madness.

```
public static double sqrtR (long x, double e, double a) {

    if (Math.abs(a * a - x) <= e) {
        return a;
    } else {
        a = (a * a + x) / (2 * a);
        return 1.0 *(sqrtR(x, e, a));
    }
}
```

Comment: funny how the data type really affects!! thanks for the notice!